# Can't get response.status react

Tags: javascript, react-native, jsx

So I am sending some params to server, but I can't get response.status. Moreover, response.ok is not working too.

```
this.state = {
    value: "",
    focused: false,
    text: "",
    uuid: this.props.navigation.state.params.uuid,
    codeConf: ''
    };
}

sendCode(uid, code) {
    fetch(' /', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
        body: JSON.stringify({"authentication": uid, "code": code})
    })
    .then(response => {
        if (response.ok){
        console.log("Code is good")
        }
        else
        {
        console.log("Code is not good Cyka")
        }
    })
}

render() {
    return (
        <Button
        title="Send code"
        onPress=
        {(code) => {this.sendCode(this.state.uuid, this.state.code)}}/>
    </View>
    )
}
}
```

Basically server return "200 OK" response if the sms code is verified, otherwise 400. So, I was thinking about proceeding user further only if response.status is 200 or response.ok is true. 
Thanks!

EDIT #1:
I have tested request using postman, everything is good.

Comment: Can you add the whole response?

Comment: Debug in dev tools and look at the value of `response`. That should tell you all you need to know. Or log out the whole response so you can actually see what fields it has.

Comment: Here is the whole response: {
    "data": {
        "id": "ab42c542-66db-4df2-974f-5fd17edfb76b",
        "gender": null,
        "status": 1,
        "surname": null,
        "name": null,
        "middlename": null,
        "borned_at": "2019-02-25T23:36:49.010638",
        "avatar": null,
        "city": null,
        "authentication": "ce1d847c-e049-44aa-9a2c-105548bf81f7"
    }
}

Comment: You might want to add the response you see in postman as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope you're doing well.

I have not enough reputation to post as a comment so I'm posting this as an answer.
Can you please check the network tab. 
Is the request type is "OPTION"?
Then you have might the cors issue.
Refer below package to allow cros.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Request is sent from my mobile phone, I am not sure if I can check request type.

Comment: can you please copy past Endpoint (Request URL)  on the browser, and open the network tab to check the actual request type.